# how can i send message to specific port from one emulator to another emulator in android?

Tags: android, android-emulator, sms, android-c2dm, android-build

I'm developing an sms application in which I'm trying to send message to a particular port (application). How to check sending & receiving of messages in emulators?

Answer (score 1):

open two emulators the emulators will open with numbers 5554 and 5556, the phone numbers is 5554 and 5556 now u can send messages between the emulators

```
sendSMS(5556,null,msg,null,null);
```

Refer the following link http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android

Comment: thanks for reply, If i try in the above way it is going to the native inbox. In my case it should go the inbox of my application i.e.,it should go to specific port.

Comment: on the reciever side you mush have to listen using broadcast reciever and catch the required message to your application

Comment: In real device it is working fine i.e., in receivers side message is going to the application inbox. but in emulator it is not working.